# If/Else not working for header

Tags: custom-post-types

I can't figure out why thisis not working. It works correctly if I just have 'events' but when I added 'guide' and 'firm-news' it doesn't changes those templates. I need to push then to H5 for SEO because we have multiple H1 tags on thousands of pages. Please help if you know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

```
    <?php //if is single event, guide, firm news
    if ( is_singular('events','guide','firm-news') ) : ?>
      <h5 class="event-subpage-header-title"><?php echo $title; ?></h5>
    <?php else : ?>
      <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually doing mistake. You have to pass 3 parameters as array not like this.
Use below code

```
<?php //if is single event, guide, firm news
    if ( is_singular( array('events','guide','firm-news') ) ) : ?>
        <h5 class="event-subpage-header-title"><?php echo $title; ?></h5>
<?php 
    else : 
?>
        <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
<?php 
    endif; 
?>
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, Mark it as accepted. 
Thanks